# Passing pipeline object as input to external application

Tags: git, powershell, pipeline

Is it possible to pass the object from the PowerShell pipeline as an argument to an external application?

I'm trying to rewrite the following bash statement in PowerShell:

`git show-ref | cut -d' ' -f2 | grep -E 'pull|merge-requests' | xargs -r -L1 git update-ref -d`

Breaking this down:

`git show-ref` lists the refs in a git repository, resulting in the following output:

```
cb8f7f4e08f64daaa18cca53d847b4866c48e006 refs/heads/master 
ec8aa722205111c5b77df5d3f1816c31377a094b refs/merge-requests/1/head 
4743558250a7b76880e46efdf980ababf20ca5f9 refs/merge-requests/1/merge 
449bf02bc4e323cb77d07c02aa461f8ef809e00d refs/tags/BeforeActivityChanges 
3e41178d9e51cf928824d008fa8e653cc2d8d74e refs/tags/WebServicesErrors_Alerting
```

`cut -d' ' -f2` then splits each line on the space and returns the second field:

```
refs/heads/master
refs/merge-requests/1/head
refs/merge-requests/1/merge
refs/tags/BeforeActivityChanges
refs/tags/WebServicesErrors_Alerting
```

`grep -E 'pull|merge-requests'` filters the results to only return those that include either the word "pull" or the word "merge-requests":

```
refs/merge-requests/1/head
refs/merge-requests/1/merge
```

`xargs -r -L1 git update-ref -d` passes the output of the grep as arguments into `git update-ref -d` which deletes the refs in question.

I've got the first three steps in the pipeline working in PowerShell:

`git show-ref | Foreach-Object {$_.split(' ')[1]} | Select-String 'pull|merge-requests'`

This outputs:

```
refs/merge-requests/1/head
refs/merge-requests/1/merge
```

How can I do the final step, to pass those results into `git update-ref -d`?  I thought passing the output of the pipeline as an argument to an external application would be a common scenario but I haven't been able to find any explanation of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Olaf's comment pointed me in the right direction: use `Foreach-Object`.  In my case the following worked:

`git show-ref | Foreach-Object {$_.split(' ')[1]} | Select-String 'pull|merge-requests' | Foreach-Object {git update-ref -d $_}`

The final `Foreach-Object` is the secret sauce, where `$_` represents the object passed through the pipeline.  You can see it's passed as an argument into `git update-ref -d`.  This technique would work with any executable that takes an argument.

By the way, the PowerShell command could be shortened by using the aliases that come out of the box:

`git show-ref | % {$_.split(' ')[1]} | sls 'pull|merge-requests' | % {git update-ref -d $_}`

However, in scripts I tend to use the full cmdlet names as they are more recognisable for anyone else trying to understand the script.